# Script Google maps differences

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

what's the difference between put the script of google maps

of this way

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=true"></script>
```

and with my google API key

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=DIzaSyDrNBNwe3GPemgne7rE54wAa5ndZOt26Hw&sensor=true"></script>
```

I try both ways and it works, but I want to know, what's the difference? is the same?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V3 of the Google Maps API does not require an API key. So you're good to go.

In the time since I answered this question Google released support for API keys in v3, letting you see usage of your API site in Google's developer console. The original answer is still accurate: API keys are not required, but they are now recommended.

Answer (score 1):

[From the Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

> Google Maps API for Business developers must not include a key in
>   their requests. Please refer to Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API
>   for Business-specific instructions.

In this case, You only need a key if you want to collect usage statistics etc. In version 2 it was required but since Google Map Version 3 doesn't require an API Key but it's recommended.

[Also check this](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/03/introducing-new-google-geocoding-web.html).